# Subversion Mixed Revisions?

Tags: svn, visual-studio-2010, revision, ankhsvn

My question is essentially the same as this one [here](http://www.mail-archive.com/hivemind-dev@jakarta.apache.org/msg01707.html).

I'm using AnkhSVN in Visual Studio 2010. I was under the impression that if I committed/updated the entire solution (I spammed both commit and update with all possible combinations), then the *entire* revision, and this means *every single file in the revision* would be updated to *one global revision*.

Lets assume there are 3 files: **A**, **B**, and **C**. **A** is at revision 1, **B** is at revision 1, and **C** is at revision 1. Let's say I revise **C** 20 times. **C** is now at revision 21. But I would expect A and B to also be at revision 21. But they're not! I look at the Repository Explorer and it says **A** and **B** are *still* at revision 1, while **C** is at revision 21. I thought the concept of Subversion was to make them all at revision 21. What the heck is going on?

A side question: if this is true, and A, B, and C really *are* at revision 21 but not displayed, then how do I get, lets say...revision 14 from A and B if they jumped from revision 1 to 21 directly?

Comment: please use only relevant tags for your questions, this has nothing to do with c#, it is a pure SVN issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The revision you are seeing is the last revision the file was updated in. So if file **A** is revision 21 and file **B** is showing revision 14 that would mean that A was updated at rev. 21 and B at rev. 14, while the repository it self might for example be at rev. 30 because of commits to other files.

Given that B has not changed between rev. 14 and rev. 30, the same code for B will be retrieved from SVN for all revs of file B from 14 to 30 or which ever later revision introduces a change to file B.

Comment: So, assuming the global revision number is at 30 (because of commits to other files), each file of the repository (this means A and B included of course) truly *is* at revision 30. The 14 and 21 beside A and B just represent the last revision, not the *current* revision number.

Comment: @Rudi, The files do not physically exist at revision 30, the last physical delta stored for the A would be at revision  21, there will not be any delta information stored after that util such time as an actual change takes place. But the experience is that all files exist at all revisions, in practice this is not the case. In fact except for the initial import only deltas (changes) exist for a file in subesequent revisions, when such changes occur.